# Jsoup возращает html отличающуюся от той которую можно получить из браузера

Tags: android, jsoup, загрузка

Имеется класс:

```
public class SourceLoaderAuth {

    private static boolean authorization = false;
    private static Connection.Response response;

    public static boolean getAuthorization() {
        return authorization;
    }

    public static void logout(){
        //Выход из личного кабинета
        response = null;
        SourceLoaderAuth.authorization = false;
    }

    public static String getUrlSource(String url) throws IOException {
        //Возращает Html, если есть авторизация иначе null
        if (!authorization) return null;
        return  Jsoup.connect(url).cookies(response.cookies()).get().html();

    }

    public static boolean loginin(String username, String password) throws IOException {

        //Если авторизация прошла успешно возвращается true иначе false
        String loginURL = "http://lk.absentomore.ru/cardsystem/";

        Log.i("Auth", "Start post");
        //делаем пост запрос
        Connection connection = HttpConnection.connect(loginURL)
                .timeout(7000)
                .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
                .data("view", "login")
                .data("username", username)
                .data("password", password)
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .followRedirects(true);
        SourceLoaderAuth.response = connection.execute();

        Log.i("Auth", "End post");
        //Проверка на получение сессии
        if (!response.url().toString().contains("view=no_user")) {
            SourceLoaderAuth.authorization = true;
            return true;
        } else {
            SourceLoaderAuth.authorization = false;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

`Jsoup.connect(url).cookies(....).get().html()` возвращает html которая отличается от скачанной через браузер (добавляются лишние теги), как можно это по править, если нельзя то как можно загрузить html используя cookies которая будет идентична скачанной с браузера.

Этим кодом страницы загружаются нормально, но как добавить работу с сессией?

```
public class SourceLoader {

    public static String getUrlSource(String url) throws IOException {
        URL u = new URL(url);
        StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(u.openStream()));

        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) a.append(inputLine);

        return a.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: как на счет JS, который при загрузке страницы может изменять HTML?

Comment: Вероятнее всего что это именно из за JS. Может какую-нибудь библиотеку посоветуете для android, которая способна выполнять JS, и возвращать изменённую html?

Comment: `WebView` самый простой вариант... Но как-то очень сильно напоминает велосипед из костылей...